# How to expose ports only within the docker network?

Tags: nginx, docker

I have a few apps running in a Docker network with their ports (`3000`,`4200`, etc) exposed. I also have an nginx container running within the same Docker network which hosts these apps on port `80` with different domain names (`site1.com`, `site2.com`).

But right now if I go directly to the ports the apps are running on (`localhost:3000`) I can access them that way too.

How do I expose those ports only to the nginx container and not the host system?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But right now if I go directly to the ports the apps are running on
>   (localhost:3000) I can access them that way too.

Thats because you are using `-p` aka `--publish` command in your `docker run`

**Explanation:**

If you want to expose ports between containers only, Do Not use `-p` or `--publish` just put them on the same docker network.

**Example:**

Lets create a new user-defined network:

```
sudo docker network create appnet
```

Lets create nginx container for reverse proxy, It should be available to outside world so we use publish.

```
sudo docker run --name nginx -d --network appnet nginx
```

Now put your apps in the same network but do not expose ports.

```
sudo docker run --name app1 -d --network appnet <app image name/id>
```

Comment: I don't think I am using publish. here is my docker run command -- `docker run -d --name "appname" -t -i -v $PWD:/usr/src/app -p 3000:3000 --net dockernet charsi/someapp`

Comment: `-p 3000:3000` this is publish, `docker run -d --name "appname" -t -i -v $PWD:/usr/src/app  --net dockernet charsi/someapp` use this instead.

Comment: sorry I am blind :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Docker [networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/).

The default network is shared with host, thus accessible from localhost. You can either configure Docker, creating a network manually, or let tools like docker-compose or Kubernetes to do it for you.